# Datatable : add row and check added row's index

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to check whether the newly added row appear in first page or not. One way of doing it is get the index, but I wonder why it doesn't work, the index for me is not accurate at all.

```
function add_row(name, time_taken, attempts) {
      var t = $('#dashboard').DataTable();
      var node = '';
      node = t.row.add([
        '',
        name,
        time_taken,
        attempts
      ]).draw().node();
      $(node).attr('id', concatSpaces(name)).hide().fadeIn('slow');

  var index = t.row('#' + concatSpaces(name)).index() // doesn't work
```

any thought? stuck for 2 hours long!

Comment: You forgot a parenthesis `t.row('#' + concatSpaces(name)).index()`.

Comment: @YvoCilon fixed my typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API method [`row().index()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().index()) returns internal index which doesn't mean row position in the table based on current sorting column and method.

You need to use the code below instead to locate index of the row based on current sorting column and method:

```
var index = table.$('tr').index(node);
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jp6rk7tc/) for code and demonstration.